# Maps hosted on my own server instead of ArcGIS servers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I know ArcGIS provides maps for me to use off of their server for the price of their services. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003vt000000

I want to share my map with other clients without requiring them to buy a license or anything.

Is it possible for me to use my own map hosted on my own server, maybe something like google maps for free?

The closest option I have seen is OpenStreetMap http://www.openstreetmap.org/. I want to add all the same layers as ArcGIS such as legend, shapes and editing.

Comment: Do you have, or are you intending to purchase,  ArcGis Server? Or are you willing to set up a MapServer environment?

Comment: I would be willing to set up my own server. The issue is sharing the map with the world. I want to make it accessible to my clients as easy and free as a general website.

Answer (score 1):

[MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) is free and open source, it requires IIS or similar to operate. There is a bit to setting it up and getting it running well, for the cost of a little effort you can have a working map server.

Consider also using [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) as a mate to your MapServer to help speed up the refresh times, it runs on [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) which can be on a different computer or the same. This would protect your *live* data from premature interrogation and may significantly improve the response time over file-based spatial data types.